# roboearth, can't do rosmake. Other image recognition options?

Tags: gazebo, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to everyone!

I follow the steps to install roboearth: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth
I'm working with diamondback, not with electric, so I change some things and I install changing the 1rst sentence to:
rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/diamondback 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
At the end of the installation it says this:
Now, type 'source /home/albert/ros/setup.bash' to set up your environment.
Add that to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc to set it up every time.

If you are not using bash please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall/NonBashShells
I do what it's said, actually I added this setup.bash to my .bashrc. The question is: is it possible to have two diferent sources in your basharc? One would be source /home/albert/ros/setup.bashsource /home/albert/ros/setup.bash and the otherone would be source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash.

After that I install the knowrob and ias_common as said in the tutorial but changing electric to diamondback. No problem.

When I try to do the rosmake roboearth it happends an error:
[rosbuild] Building package re_ontology
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests re_ontology
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [gazebo] of [re_ontology]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 're_ontology'.
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)

I try to install gazebo from http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo doing:
svn co http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo
rosmake --rosdep-install

but it happends an other error:

[rosbuild] Building package gazebo
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests gazebo
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [gazebo_msgs] of [gazebo]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'gazebo'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)

After that I think i need gazebo_msgs, I do it from here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo_msgs and I get this error:

[rosbuild] Building package gazebo
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests gazebo
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [common_rosdeps] of [gazebo]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'gazebo'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)

At this point I've tried to install this common_rosdeps from: http://www.ros.org/wiki/common_rosdeps but I can not do it. I run this comand:
hg co http://www.ros.org/wiki/common_rosdeps and get this answer:
abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!

What do I need to do to get roboearth installed? I really want to do image recognision with this software.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11496/roboearth,-can%27t-do-rosmake.-other-image-recognition-options?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, the main problem was that I was useing diamondback not electric.

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the problems are all related to missing dependencies. Please make sure that all required packages are in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in every terminal you are using. You'll have to source the setup.bash in each of them. Try `rospack find PACKAGE` to check whether the package can be found. If you use Ubuntu, you may want to consider using the debian packages for the standard packages like gazebo since dependencies will then be automatically resolved by the package manager.

If you try to source multiple files, the variable definitions from the last setup.bash will be used. Normally, you only need this in case you have different ROS environments, e.g. parallel installations for diamondback and electric. In that case, you can define a bash alias to load the respective file manually.

best,
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

common_rosdeps seems to be a new package in Electric. You'll need to use a Diamondback-compatible version of Gazebo, e.g. https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/diamondback/

As mentioned in my previous mail, I'd recommend to use Ubuntu and the binary .deb packages which automatically resolve such dependency problems for common packages.

cheers
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1